# Run a command using some text

Tags: command-line, filelink

What I want to achieve is making a string command `start server` run the command `wine ./_server.exe`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an alias for your command.

Edit your `~/.bash_aliases` file and add your command there.

Example:

```
alias start-server='wine ./_server.exe'
```

More details -> [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/how-to-use-aliases-to-customize-ubuntu-commands/)

Comment: No problem. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The particular syntax you use (`start server`) brings to mind [Upstart session jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job), since it looks you want to use it as a service. Create a file in `~/.config/upstart/` called `some-server.conf` (change the name to suit your need, but it must have the `.conf` extension).

As contents use:

```
description "Describe your server"

script
    cd /to/where/ever/_server.exe/is
    wine ./_server.exe
end script
```

Now you can actually do:

```
start some-server
```

and

```
stop some-server
```

to start and stop the server. You could look at the [`respawn`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn) option too, if you want the program to restart if it exited.

Comment: Omg, how did I not read this comment! This solved my problem (which i've spend 2 hours on..) to run it as a process, thanks! (EDIT: I can't upvote your answer.. sorry about that)

Comment: @RemyKooistra as a service, you mean? (That's OK. :) )

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant haha